# jQuery's maskedinput with negative integer

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

How I can allow negative numbers in my mask using jQuery Masked Input plugin?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Masked input plugins are for structured data, like social security "numbers" and telephone "numbers" (both of which are neither positive nor negative).  You should consider using a validation plugin instead, if you're working with real numbers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You probably can, as long as you specify a sign for both cases: `+/-`. That way it is still structured data.

Comment: @Asad: I don't see any way to do that with the aforementioned plugin.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can add to the `definitions` object at the beginning of the plugin. Add a `-` key (or some other symbol you don't want to use as a literal), and set the value to `"[\+\-]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by going to the "documentation" page for the plugin.
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Then reference the section that starts with "You can now supply your own mask definitions."

```
jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
   $("#eyescript").mask("~9.99 ~9.99 999");
});
```

---

So you would probably want something like....

```
jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]?';
   $("#eyescript").mask("~999999999");
});
```

I'm assuming the question mark at the end '[+-]?' will work as expected for a regex fragment.

Comment: Hi @LastCoder, with your solution the input accepts negative numbers but when the input lost focus (blur),  input content is lost.

Comment: @Thiago Burgo - if you create a jsfiddle.net reproducing the issue then someone might be able to help. It could very well be the plugin won't allow [+-]? "?" denoting that the + or - doesn't have to be there.

Comment: your code works fine, I solved my problem put remain mask to optional, like:  `$("#eyescript").mask("~?999999999");`, sorry, my bad!  Thanks!